# Facebook iOS SDK 3.2 produces error when using logPurchase:currency:

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

With the new Facebook iOS SDK 3.2, whenever I fire a call to

```
[FBInsights logPurchase:price currency:currencyCode];
```

It results with the following response -

```
FBSDKLog: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x202319a0 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 100;
        message = "(#100) The specified events list contains unrecognized events that cannot be logged";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 400;
}
```

Sounds like a bug of Facebook, because there isn't much room for mistake here...

Any idea why this error is showing?